# Data not shown when directly accessing a URL in nested Ember Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a nested route setup as I would like to have my templates nested as well. The route setup looks like this:

```
...

      this.route('posts', function() {
        this.route('post', {path: ':post_id'}, function() {
          this.route('comments',  {path: 'comments'}, function() {
            this.route('comment',  {path: ':comment_id'});
          });
        });
      });

...
```

Potentially, my URL could look something like this:
`/posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id`

If I navigate via `{{link-to}}` then I have no problem, however, if I go directly to a specific URL via the browser, that's when things going wrong. Imagine that my comments page lists the comments associated with the post (post_id) I'm looking at. The problem is going there directly, like typing in `/posts/123/comments/56` doesn't load the list of comments, only the comment itself. Here is how my routes are setup:

```
// routes/posts.js
...
model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('post');
}
...

// routes/posts/post.js
...
model(params) {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('post', params.post_id);
}
...

// routes/posts/post/comments.js
...
model(params) {
    let post=this.modelFor('posts/post');
    return post.get('comments');

}
...

// routes/posts/post/comments/comment.js
...
model(params) {


    return this.store.findRecord('comment', params.comment_id);

}
...
```

If I type in `/posts/123/comments/56`, no list is displayed from the comments.js template.

If I type in `/posts/123/comments`, only the first comment is displayed from the comments.js.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though I feel like it has something to do with modelFor. How do I properly populate/hydrate the post's comments list when I go directly to a comment in that post URL rather than navigating there via link-to?

**UPDATE 1:**
Here are the models:

```
// post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string"),
    articles: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true})
});
// comment.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string")
});
```

I've connected it to mirage.

Here is a sample of the comments fixture:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Apple"
    },
...
```

and the posts fixture:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "A post with fruits for comments",
        commentIds: [1, 2]
    },
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've added my template code for `templates/posts/post/comments.js`

```
Comments.js!
{{outlet}}
<ol>
    {{#each model as |comment|}}
        <li>{{#link-to "posts.post.comments.comment" comment}} {{comment.title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

I've also updated the comment.js route above, reducing its complexity.

Comment: Can you show us what your models look like and the JSON that back those models

Comment: I updated the post with some more info. The data is there and works without the URL, it's just the nested routes break down when you try to access it directly.

Comment: `this.modelFor('posts/post')` is it returning post model and is that working for you? i thought it would be `this.modelFor('posts.post')`.  anyway correct me if yours working.

Comment: I've tried both with / and . with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your router definitions - the URL /post/123/comments/56 does not exists. Your router defines URL with the following structure /posts/56/comment/123 (notice singular comment not comments) - your route name is comments however you told ember that the path it should resolve is comment - singular. So, try accessing /post/123/comment/56 instead of comments.
Also, no reason to call this.modelFor('posts/post') from nested comments route - all you should need is modeFor('post'). 
And the last thing, inside the comment route you should only need to look for a give comment no need to resolve the parent model - you already have a unique comment_id - store.findRecord('comment', comment_id) should work.

Comment: That was an error on my part when writing the question here, it should have been comments. I've corrected it.

Comment: I tried using just modelFor('post') but then I get an error: `Error while processing route: posts.post.comments.comment Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. Also for your last point, you are right about not needing to complicate it... I've reduced it to what you've suggested. Still, when I go to a specific comment, I'm expecting to see a list of other comments within that post (as per my template). I've added that template. This works if I use the link-to to get there, but not if I directly go there.

Comment: I also tried modelFor('posts') in comments.js which didn't give an error, but then didn't display any list of comments for that post.